# Kotlin with ANT build

Tags: java, ant, kotlin

I've read the documentation for using Kotlin inside a Java / ANT project.
I've integrated the build `.xml` file with:

```
<typedef resource="org/jetbrains/kotlin/ant/antlib.xml">
   <classpath>
      <pathelement location="lib/kotlin-ant.jar"/>
   </classpath>
</typedef>
```

But I noticed the minimal required libraries for `kotlin-ant` are:

```
kotlin-compiler.jar
kotlin-preloader.jar
kotlin-reflect.jar
kotlin-runtime.jar
kotlin-script-runtime.jar
kotlin-stdlib.jar
```

and they must be placed in the same directory as `kotlin-ant`.
Do you confirm this is the correct approach for compiling with ANT?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than copying kotlin-ant.jar in your project lib directory, you could try referencing directly the original one in kotlinc installation. In this case, it should also find the other required .jar, which are in the same directory.
It worked for me, and I could compile and execute simple stand-alone kotlin programs, only using standard kotlin/java packages.